# Editing and releasing an older version of master by moving current changes onto a branch

Tags: git

I need to roll out some changes from my master branch, but without a couple of commits that are already on there.

If I branch off from 'master' with my current changes, and then go back to 'master' and revert to a previous commit. Will my branch stay the same as 'master' before the git-revert?

In my head I feel this would allow me to change 'master', roll out a release and then cherry-pick the other commits off the branch I made earlier back onto 'master'.

Can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you want to deploy a previous version of master right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout master   # switch to master
git branch branchname # create a new branch with the changes from master 
git reset --hard commitname #reset the master back.
```

this is will set your master back by some commits.

but are you sure you don't want to just

```
git checkout REVISION # set the working dir to another commit.
```

changing history on an already published branch is a bad idea.
just going unwinding changes in your working tree will give you the commit you'd like to have without actually changing the view of somebody else. this is called detached head mode.
a more in depth explaination can be found [here](http://gitolite.com/concepts/detached-head.html)

Comment: I would love to just branch off from an old commit and rollout from that, but our rollout script only uses master and I currently don't have access to edit the script.

Would I be able to cherry-pick from the branch back to master after I have released?

Comment: @gMok: look at the link I've posted. just go back to the commit you'd like to go with `git checkout` then create a branch from there: `git checkout -b` is your friend. commit as much as you like. and of course cherry picking will work. you can also consider just merging the branch back to master.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the link too - quite valuable information.